# Agent is not in a network at Rack Store and Rack Pick

Tags: anylogic

i`m trying to take pallets from a conveyor to a Rack and after some time the Picker(Ressource) should take the Pallet out of the Rack to a conveyor again. But if i try to use the Rack Store, i get the error: The agent is not in a network. I think the problem is the Ressource(Picker), because without it the Rack Store is working.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, assuming you are using a conveyor from the material handling library, after the conveyor use a conveyorExit block.

The conveyorExit block allows your agents to move smoothly from a conveyor network to the normal network.

If you are using a conveyor from the process modeling library, then it means that you are not connecting your networks correctly and you should be sure you conveyor path is connected in the same network as the path in which your palletRack is located.

Comment: i tried it like you described it. But i get still the same Error. But if i turn "move agent to" at the Rack Store to aisle, then the Rack Store is working, but then i get the error "the agent is not in a network" at the Rack Pick.

Comment: And my Ressource(Picker) dont use the path, he just take the shortest way

Answer (score 0):

This might fix. In my case: I had 4 process flows of the same type of agent (ie. agent Type: product) coming into the RackPallet. Two is a to model processes before agent:product is stored in Rack, and the other two is to model the initial Stock of the Rack.

This solved my problme: I put the code
`agent.setNetwork(network2);`
before the RackStore of the initial Stock process flows, and it worked. I think this is because when we model initial Fill, the agent is not set on a on network yet.